# Solving cyclic dependency graphs in a DI Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I need to solve how to manage an co-dependent instances registered in a DI container I've created.

I'd created a simple DI container by constructor injection that works fine for simple tasks. But exists an bigger issue that is when I register two instances are co-dependant (e.g. An class A that needs a B instance, but the B needs an A instance), falls into stackoverflow.

```cs
public class DIContainer : IContainer
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _registeredTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();

        public object GetInstance(Type type)
        {
            if (_registeredTypes.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                return _registeredTypes[type]();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private object CreateInstance(Type type)
        {
            var constructor = type.GetConstructors()
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.GetParameters().Length)
                .First();

            var args = constructor.GetParameters().Select(p => GetInstance(p.ParameterType)).Where(a => a != null).ToArray();

            return Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
        }

        public T Get<T>()
        {
            return (T)GetInstance(typeof(T));
        }

        public void Register<I, C>()
        {
            Register(typeof(I), typeof(C));
        }

        public void RegisterSinglenton<I, C>()
            where C : I
        {
            var instance = CreateInstance(typeof(C));
            RegisterSinglenton<I>((C)instance);
        }

        public void RegisterSinglenton<T>(T obj)
        {
            _registeredTypes.Add(typeof(T), () => obj);
        }

        public void Register(Type service, Type implementation)
        {
            _registeredTypes.Add(service, () => CreateInstance(implementation));
        }
    }
```

I know that the most of the people will advice to use an already implemented container (like ninject or autofac), but this is a solution that I need to implement for a personal project and will apreciate all the advices you can give me.

Comment: In most modern DI containers circular dependencies are also result an exception (not StackOverflow, of course, but still) to be thrown. Alternative way is to use property injection or inject some kind of "proxy" object that will delegate future calls to an actual instance.

Comment: There is no container that can resolve a circular dependency, you need to fix your code as that is just not possible.

Comment: This is not DI problem, this is problem with the code structure. Change it, that implementations registered with Di container will not depend on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But exists an bigger issue that is when I register two instances are co-dependant (e.g. An class A that needs a B instance, but the B needs an A instance)

This is a [Code Smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that something has been (most likely) designed poorly.  Usually the *best option* is to redesign/refactor the requirements to remove this type of circular dependency.  One of the biggest problems with circular dependencies is the ability for each dependency to call the other in a way that causes each to call a method on the other in a sort of *recursive* way until the system fails with a stack-overflow.

> I need to implement for a personal project and will apreciate all the advices you can give me.

That being said, there are few ways to do this if it's *truly needed*.  In my personal opinion, the next best option (after redesign/refactor) is use a deferred/delegate constructor injection.  This might look like:

```
 // "Func Factory"
 public class A
 {
   private Func<B> _bFactory;
   private B b
   {
     if (_b == null)
     {
      _b = _bFactory();
     }
     return _b;
   }

   public A(Func<B> bFactory)
   {
     _bFactory = bFactory;
   }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
     b.DoSomething();
   }
 }
```

or a cleaner solution (IMHO)

```
 // "Lazy Factory"
 public class A
 {
   private Lazy<B> _b;

   public A(Lazy<B> b)
   {
     _b = b;
   }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
     b.Value.DoSomething();
   }
 }
```

In both the previous example, the construction of B is deferred until it is actually required.  (Autofac supports both of these out-of-the-box without any additional registration; [Dynamic Instantiation (Func)](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b) and [Delayed Instantiation (Lazy)](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#delayed-instantiation-lazy-b))

Another option (I'm not a fan) is to use Property Injection.

```
public class A
{
  // One way is to create an attribute for signaling a property to inject
  [MyDIFrameworkAttributeForPropertyInjection]
  public B B1 { get; set; }

  // Another way is to use reflection to loop through all properties
  // and if a Type is found in the container, inject it after instantiation
  public B B2 { get; set; }

  public A()
  {
    // WARNING, B1 AND B2 WILL ALWAYS BE NULL
    // IN THE CONSTRUCTOR AND ANY METHOD THE CONSTRUCTOR CALLS
    // BECAUSE IT CANNOT BE ASSIGNED UNTIL THE CLASS IS INSTANTIATED
  }
}
```

While this does work and seems to be clean, it's not always apparent to other programmers when they can use the Injected Property to do work (nor that it is injected at all (B2)).

Answer (score 0):

Most modern DI containers do not allow circular dependencies via constructor injection. However, there are some strategies to overcome such limitations. For example, imagine you have class `A` that depends on class `B` and class `B` depends on class `A`.

1. The best way is to refactor client's code to get rid of circular dependencies. This will also make client's code better overall. In this case your code don't need to be changed.
2. Use `Lazy` in client's code or some kind of other holders, for example, Castle Windsor has support for `Lazy` - https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/whats-new-3.0.md#added-support-for-lazyt-components.
3. Use property injection. Because there is no need to initialize object properties on construction (they will be initialized with default values), we can create both instances of classes `A` and `B`. When we have both instances we can set their properties, `A.b = instanceOfB` and `B.a = instanceOfA`. This is the way recommended, for example, by Autofac, see https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html.
4. There is also more sophisticated way that will allow client's to use still use constructor injection - lazy initialization with some "proxy" objects. On creation of `B` instead of injecting instance of `A` we inject some kind of `FakeA` instance that does not have any dependencies. Same with constructing `A`. Now we have both `A` and `B` instances and all we need is to link them to their `Fake`s. `Fake` should inherit `A` for `FakeA` and `B` for `FakeB` and have a property that will be set to a reference of "real" object. So in fact we use property injection, but this is not visible to clients code. Such `Fake`s can be created with some reflection magic, see https://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/, for example.

Both third and forth options will have limitation, that both your code and client's have to consider. For example, with properties injection there might be errors when client's code will try to access property before your container sets it to an instance of an object. With the forth options problems are more sophisticated just like the solution itself. For example, there is no way to inherit from a sealed class, so there is no way to create a proxy.

Comment: Thank you! Is very appreciated. I have time searching for a solution for this, and I've tried something with Property injection, but it looked so ugly that I had to make the consult. It was very helpful.